# X-editable for Bootstrap 4 Beta 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, popover, x-editable

Unfortunately, [Bootstrap 3 X-editable 1.5.1](https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/index.html) does not work with `Popover.js` and `Bootstrap 4 Beta 2`.

[image]

Does anyone know how to adapt it? Can anyone share the working version?

The same examples one with BS3 another with BS4

[X-editable for Bootstrap 3](http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/63/)

[X-editable for Bootstrap 4 Beta 2](http://jsfiddle.net/testone/djLo7yb4/)

Comment: hey that X-editable is for Bootstrap 3, not 4, that's the problem! if you can, use version 3

Comment: @KresimirPendic, I added to same examples you can see that with Bootstrap 4 beta 2 does nit work :(

Comment: There has been a ticket raised over at Github: https://github.com/vitalets/x-editable/issues/1043

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Bootstrap 4 use this dev version - https://github.com/Talv/x-editable/tree/develop/dist/bootstrap4-editable/js